# how to find base vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

before I finally give up on this question,how to find a base and dimension for
http://up419.siz.co.il/up1/2wcey3wyqyjz.png

$W_1=\begin{cases} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \cr x_2 \cr x_3 \cr x_4 \end{bmatrix}, x_1-x_2+x_3-x_4=0 \end{cases}$

w1 c V
$V=R^4$
thanks for the help

Comment: Note that the equation allows you to write $x_1$ in terms of $x_2,x_3,x_4$ as $x_1=x_2-x_3+x_4$. Giving $x_2,x_3,x_4$ the values $(x_2,x_3,x_4)=(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$ you get the corresponding values for $x_1=1,-1,1$. Then the vectors $(1,1,0,0),(-1,0,1,0),(1,0,0,1)$ are a basis of $W_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector in that set can be written as:
$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(x_2-x_3+x_4,x_2,x_3,x_4)=x_2(1,1,0,0)+x_3(-1,0,1,0)+x_4(1,0,0,1)$

The base is formed by the those three vectors and, therefore, the dimension is 3.

Comment: thanks, it helped me understand